# If command breaking my PHP script

Tags: php, html

I don't really know what's going on here.

If I have this as my code:

```
if($_POST['expOncology'] !="") {
    $varOnc = $_POST['expOncology'];

    if ($varOnc="min") {
        $sql_extra[] = "(exp_onc='minimal expertise' OR exp_onc='some expertise' OR exp_onc='high level of expertise' OR exp_onc='expert')";
    }

    if ($varOnc="some") {
        $sql_extra[] = "(exp_onc='some expertise' OR exp_onc='high level of expertise' OR exp_onc='expert')";
    }

    if ($varOnc="high") {
        $sql_extra[] = "(exp_onc='high level of expertise' OR exp_onc='expert')";
    }
}
```

It works fine and the proper results are shown.

However, if I add one more if block, to make it this:

```
if($_POST['expOncology'] !="") {
    $varOnc = $_POST['expOncology'];

    if ($varOnc="min") {
        $sql_extra[] = "(exp_onc='minimal expertise' OR exp_onc='some expertise' OR exp_onc='high level of expertise' OR exp_onc='expert')";
    }

    if ($varOnc="some") {
        $sql_extra[] = "(exp_onc='some expertise' OR exp_onc='high level of expertise' OR exp_onc='expert')";
    }

    if ($varOnc="high") {
        $sql_extra[] = "(exp_onc='high level of expertise' OR exp_onc='expert')";
    }

    if ($varOnc="expert") {
        $sql_extra[] = "(exp_onc='expert')";
    }
}
```

It does not work as intended at all, even if I'm not even selecting "expert" from the drop down list. Shouldn't that code not even run if expOncology isn't set to expert? Why is even affecting the code if I'm not satisfying its conditions to run?

Comment: This `$varOnc="min"` isn't comparing..

Comment: I don't know, from when single `=` is used for comparison?!?!?!

Comment: See [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: All conditionals are currently met. Do you maybe mean the SQL later fails?

Comment: that's weird, I was accidentally using single = for every other comparison before this and it was working fine...

Comment: Also if comparing the same variable multiple times consider using `switch`. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if($_POST['expOncology'] !="") {
  $varOnc = $_POST['expOncology'];
  if ($varOnc=="min"){
    $sql_extra[] = "(exp_onc='minimal expertise' OR exp_onc='some     expertise' OR exp_onc='high level of expertise' OR exp_onc='expert')";
   }
  if ($varOnc=="some"){
    $sql_extra[] = "(exp_onc='some expertise' OR exp_onc='high level of expertise' OR exp_onc='expert')";
  }
 if ($varOnc=="high"){
    $sql_extra[] = "(exp_onc='high level of expertise' OR exp_onc='expert')";
 }
}
```

with == it's better to compare ;)

Answer (score 0):

Condition like `$varOnc="something"` will always return `true`.

You should use a `==` or `===` (if you want check the data types).
Your code should look like this

```
if($_POST['expOncology'] != "") {
    $varOnc = $_POST['expOncology'];

    if ($varOnc == "min") {
        $sql_extra[] = "(exp_onc='minimal expertise' OR exp_onc='some expertise' OR exp_onc='high level of expertise' OR exp_onc='expert')";
    }

    if ($varOnc == "some") {
        $sql_extra[] = "(exp_onc='some expertise' OR exp_onc='high level of expertise' OR exp_onc='expert')";
    }

    if ($varOnc == "high") {
        $sql_extra[] = "(exp_onc='high level of expertise' OR exp_onc='expert')";
    }

    if ($varOnc == "expert") {
        $sql_extra[] = "(exp_onc='expert')";
    }
}
```